# I am not a company but am trying to avoid having to buy multiple individual iOS licenses

Tags: ios, license

I'm developing an app for iOS and since it's not going to be published by my company it looks like I have to get my own developer license.

I can live with that, but there's a part of the app that I'm stuck on that I need to get a third-party to help me work through. Some of the libraries I use for the project have problems with the simulator, so what I need to know is:

Am I stuck having to buy two iOS developer licenses (one for the third-party programmer, one for myself)?

One possibility would be for me to keep testing this person's code and send them the output, but I can't think of an obvious way to automate that and it just seems suboptimal. Any other suggestions (short of starting my own company)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a member to Your developer program if You enroll as company. You won't have to buy another account.

Here's the info from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php) (You need to have developer account in order to enter this link).

> If you are enrolled in the iOS Developer Program as a company and hold either the Agent or Admin role, you can invite co-workers to join your development team by visiting the People tab in Member Center.

Comment: Did you read the title to my post?